# PHP Mail function errors - Olia Studio

Tags: php, email, web

I do not own Olia Studio, but I know the person who owns it very well. I've come across a bunch load of erros when i tried to send a email (Message) to her via the website. It's a new business and the owner dosn't need these issues right now, any help?

Here are the erros:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in /home/liveolia/public_html/health-and-fitness-contact-us.php on line 35

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Mail/smtp.php on line 365

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 448

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 465

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 472

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 515

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 519

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Mail/smtp.php on line 376

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 597

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 600

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 603

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 515

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 519

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 621

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 802

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 806

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 814

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 818

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 822

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 827

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 649

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Mail/smtp.php on line 249

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Mail/smtp.php on line 285

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 945

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 948

Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Mail.php on line 254

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 975

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 978

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 1054

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 1057

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 1117

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 1127

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 1132

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 489

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 263

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 492

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/liveolia/public_html/libraries/Net/SMTP.php on line 495

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/liveolia/public_html/health-and-fitness-contact-us.php:35) in /home/liveolia/public_html/health-and-fitness-contact-us.php on line 38
```

The website is oliastudio.co.uk - Help is needed!

Comment: you're running old code on a new php, and it's rightfully complaining about bad code usage.

Comment: @MarcB - Ok, any ideas on how to fix it? I don't know if the owner has FTP access to the site, i'll try my best to find out more info, thanks for telling me!

Comment: quick fix: turn off warnings. better fix: beat whoever installed obsolete code with a wet fish until they agree to fix it.

Comment: PEAR discusses this. Use Mail2 etc. http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=14

Comment: @Twisty - Can you explain to me how i could change code to make it work, the owner really needs this to be fixed...

Comment: Install `Mail2` via pear commands like you did with `Mail`, it may already be installed. Good examples are hard to come by, but I will dig out one I have working. Read more here: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail2/docs/latest/Mail/Mail2.html - For the most part, should be able to replace commands from `Mail` to `Mail2`

Comment: http://clockwerx.blogspot.com/2014/06/php5-mail-netsocket-and-netsmtp.html - still looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the example. I suggest switching to Mail2 from PEAR. It will not throw exceptions. My example uses MIME as well to format the message properly. I did not want to rely on my SMTP Relay, so I push mail directly to a recipients MX Record. If you do this, make sure the SPF Record has `a` or `ip4` flags for your server. Details like `$name` and `$mail` are pulled form DB in another part of the script. Yours will be different.

Example Code:

```
<?php
include 'Mail2.php';
include 'Mail/mime.php';

function getMX($email){
     $mailparts = explode('@', $email);
     $hostname = $mailparts[1];
     $b_mail_avail = getmxrr( $hostname, $mx_records, $mx_weights );
     if($b_mail_avail){
          return $mx_records[0];
     } else {
          return false;
     }
}

$subject = "Reset Example Password Request";

$txtparams = array(
     'charset' => 'utf-8',
     'content_type' => 'text/plain',
     'encoding' => 'quoted/printable'
);

$txtMessage  = "Hello $name,\n";
$txtMessage .= "A request to reset your Password has been initiated.\n";
$txtMessage .= "To complete this, please follow the link below.\n\n";
$txtMessage .= "http://www.example.com/admin/admin-login.php?a=confirm&c=$c\n\n";
$txtMessage .= "If you did not request to reset your password, follow this link below.\n\n";
$txtMessage .= "http://www.exmaple.com/admin/admin-login.php?a=deny&c=$c\n\n";

$htmlparams = array(
     'charset' => 'utf-8',
     'content_type' => 'text/html',
     'encoding' => 'quoted/printable'
);
$htmlMessage  = "<html><body><p>Hello $name,</p>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "<p>A request to reset your Password has been initiated.</p>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "<p>To complete this, please follow the link below.<br><br>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "<a href='http://www.exmaple.com/admin/admin-login.php?a=confirm&c=$c'>http://www.exmaple.com/admin/admin-login.php?a=confirm</a>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "If you did not request to reset your password, follow this link below.<br><br>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "<a href='http://www.exmaple.com/admin/admin-login.php?a=deny&c=$c'>http://www.exmaple.com/admin/admin-login.php?a=deny&c=$c</a>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "</body></html>";

$headers  = array(
     "To" => "$name <$mail>",
     "From" => "webmaster@exmaple.com",
     "Reply-To" => "donotreply@example.com",
     "Subject" => $subject,
     "X-Request-Address" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
     "Content-Type" => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
);

$mime_params = array(
     'text_encoding' => '7bit',
     'text_charset' => 'UTF-8',
     'html_charset' => 'UTF-8',
     'head_charset' => 'UTF-8'
);
$mime = new Mail_mime();

$mime->setTXTBody($txtMessage);
$mime->setHTMLBody($htmlMessage);

$body = $mime->get($mime_params);
$hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);

$hostname = getMX($email);
if($hostname){
     $mail = Mail2::factory('smtp',
          array(
               'host' => $hostname,
               'auth' => false
          )
     );

     // Send Email
     $sm = $mail->send("$name <$email>", $hdrs, $body);
     if(PEAR::isError($sm)){
          $smtpError = $sm->getMessage();
          // Do error handling stuff
     }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps and you can configure other mail methods as described here: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail2/docs/latest/Mail/Mail2.html